# semi-simple and completely reducibility

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness, semisimple-lie-algebras

Many books state completely reducible as semi-simple. This is quite puzzling since Semi-simple means there is no proper abelian sub-algebra in the Lie algebra. How could this be connected to complete reducibility. More importantly, Why group has an abelian subgroup cannot be complete reducible.

Also, Is there an example of a compact but not semi-simple Lie group.

Thanks.

Comment: I know many semisimple Lie algebras with proper abelian subalgebras. Are you sure you're looking at the right definition?

Comment: To your last question, if the source you are learning from never brought up the torus $S^1 \simeq \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ as basic example of a compact Lie group, you should throw it away.